# MYSQL: Multiple "contradicting" conditions on one column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to create a query that ONLY outputs members if they meet 2 conditions.

The first condition:
If the user has a matching "courseID".

The second condition: 
If the user doesn't have a matching "courseID".

Obviously this is contradicting so let me explain.

I have two tables...

**members**

- ID
- email

**certifications**

- ID
- memberID
- courseID

When members complete a course they gain a certification. The certification stores their memberID and the courseID. Members can have multiple certifications.

The end goal is to create an email sending list to promote courses.

Let's say we have two courses. 
"Beginner"(courseID=1) and "Intermediate"(courseID=2).

One member could have both certifications, one for each course. Another member could just have the one, the "Beginner" certification.

I want to send a promotional email to all members who have the "Beginner" certification. However I want to exclude any members with the "Intermediate" certification.

The problem I can't seem to overcome is how to exclude the members with the "Intermediate" certification.

**I have simplified this example, in truth there is a vast amount of different certification types **

Below is a rough query I've been trying... I've tried so, so many different queries.

Any help would be great, thank you.

```
// Look Up Recipients
$recipientsQuery = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT DISTINCT(email) 
FROM $memberTable
LEFT JOIN $certificationsTable
ON $memberTable.ID = $certificationsTable.memberID
WHERE courseID = 4 AND courseID != 5
");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if beginner was stored as 1 and intermediate as 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.ID, m.email
   , MAX(IF(c.courseID = 4, 1, 0)) AS hasCourse4
   , MAX(IF(c.courseID = 5, 1, 0)) AS hasCourse5
FROM members AS m 
LEFT JOIN certifications AS c ON m.ID = c.memberID
HAVING hasCourse4 = 1 AND hasCourse5 = 0
;
```

Alternatively, you could join certs to members to certs, this *might* be faster:

```
SELECT m.email
FROM certifications AS c1
INNER JOIN members AS m ON c1.memberID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN certifications AS c2 ON m.ID = c2.memberID AND c2.courseID = 5
WHERE c1.courseID = 4 AND c2.courseID IS NULL
;
```

Comment: I got the second query working, thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: @DeanRidgeley Out of curiosity, did you have any problems with the first one?

Comment: I did try the first one and had no luck but looking back I think it was my fault as forgot to make a tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..  Get what you need, and take away what you dont..

```
SELECT *
FROM $memberTable
LEFT JOIN $certificationsTable USING (ID)
WHERE courseID = 4
AND ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM $memberTable
    LEFT JOIN $certificationsTable USING (ID)
    WHERE courseID = 5
)
```

Comment: `AND ID` is ambigous. And actually, the outer query doesn't need to be a LEFT join, and the subquery in the where probably doesn't actually need the join to members.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help. I think it's nearly there but I can't quite get it working. I'm finding it a little difficult to see how the tables are joined? When I tried your code it displayed one person which is the correct number at the moment, however it was the wrong person, didn't even have a certification. Could you help me out again please?

Comment: Also, the outer query's join condition is wrong; it is matching up the `members.ID` with the `certifications.ID`, instead of `certifications.memberID`

Comment: Hi Chris, when you next have a change would you please help me finish this problem. I've been stuck on it for the past 10 hours + and I feel it's so close. It looks like your right about the ID being the wrong ID but i'm not sure how to fix it. If you could help once more that would be great, thanks.